# Can we match subgraphs in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know that in cypher it is possible to match paths like this :

```
MATCH p=(n)-[r]-(m)
RETURN p
```

But is there a way to do something similar but for subgraphs, i.e groups of nodes and relationships which are not expressible in the form of a path ?

I have something like this in my mind :

```
MATCH subgraph=[(n)-[r]-(m)-[s]-(p), (m)-[j]-(u)]
RETURN subgraph
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [APOC path expander](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/path-expander/) procedures serve your needs. You have much control over how the graph should be traversed.

However, you don't get a subgraph into one variable as you have in mind:

`CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(n, { ... }) YIELD path` will return multiple rows (one row for each found path).

`CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, { ... }) YIELD nodes, relationships` will return lists of all found nodes and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH path1=(n)-[r]-(m)-[s]-(p),
      path2=(m)-[j]-(u)
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(nodes(path1),nodes(path2)) AS subGraphNodes,
       apoc.coll.toSet(rels(path1),rels(path2)) AS subGraphRelationships
```

Would return the distinct nodes and rels for each matching subgraph.

If you just need the virtual subgraph, you can use

```
apoc.graph.fromPaths()
```